# How do I match an orthographic type camera to an orthographic image?

Tags: camera, mathematics, orthographic

There's a program called **fSpy** in which you can draw lines on an image, and it will in turn give you a camera position and rotation, however it doesn't seem to work with orthographic images.

I have an image I want to recreate to scale, but it's in a trimetric view, I know all the angles to it, but it requires a lot of math to set up the camera and I don't think I'm able experienced enough to figure it out on my own. I tried eyeballing it, and while I can get close enough, I'd rather get it as close to perfection as I can. Is there some easy math algorithm or software feature that I can use to set up the camera? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a camera in orthographic view, to cover *exact* dimensions of an image – here's one way of doing it:

1. Add your picture as an image plane. **Note:** I recommend using Blender's stock addon, [Images as Planes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/images_as_planes.html) for that.
2. Make sure you have a camera in the scene and that it's attached to the render output. **Note:** If you have multiple cams, select your preferred one and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 0</kbd> to make it the render cam.
3. In Object Mode, select the image plane by *clicking* on it. **Note:** Marquee-select won't work for next step.
4. Press *N* to bring up the sidebar (aka N-panel) if it isn't open already.
5. Select the *Item* tab in the N-panel.
6. Under *Dimensions* properties, copy the *highest* value (*X* or *Y*). **Note:** To get *exact sizes*, click on the properties.
7. Click/select the Camera and refer to its *Item* tab in the N-panel. **Note:** Make sure to zero out any values in the *X/Y/Z* *Location* and *Rotation* properties.
8. Set Camera's *Scale* *X/Y/Z* to *1*.
9. Now, in the Camera's *Location* *Z* property: paste the largest size that you copied from step 6. **Note:** Remove the trailing unit (<kbd>M</kbd> in my case) before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The Camera will move in position.
10. Open the Camera's *Object Data Properties* in the *Properties* editor.
11. Set *Type* to *Orthographic* if you haven't already, and paste in the same value you copied from step 6. **Note:** Minus the trailing unit (<kbd>M</kbd> in my case).
12. Open the *Output* panel in the *Properties* editor.
13. Under *Resolution*, enter the same dimensions as the image plane's (see step 6), ***but** you'll want to raise the decimals upwards to a desired size*.
14. In the *3D Viewport*, press <kbd>NumPad 0</kbd> to see the Camera view.

Now the Camera should snugly fit around the exact same proportions as the image!

[image]

Comment: Umm, not exactly, what im asking for is how to match the angle of an orthographic image to a camera. Think of an isometric image, to align the camera to that, you have to have it 45 degress to the side, and 35.264 up, so that all angles are 120 degrees. but of course thats only isometric, im trying to make a trimetric image, and make it the exact same angles to use as a refrence. This was also helpful, but for something completely different, thanks anyway!

Comment: haha. umm indeed! I wish know how I managed to misinterpret your question to such degree, but apparently I did :-) Oh well, I'm at loss as far as the answer to your real question here. Hope you find an answer. Try BlenderArtists maybe. They're quite speedy at answering things like this over there.